# gitk crashes when viewing commit containing emoji: X Error of failed request: BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)

Tags: x11, git, unicode, emoji

I'm able to open `gitk` but it crashes as soon as I open a commit whom changes contains an emoji (not the commit message).

#### Error

```
❯ gitk --all
X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RenderAddGlyphs)
  Serial number of failed request:  6687
  Current serial number in output stream:  6706
```

#### Env

```
❯ cat /etc/os-release --plain
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="20 (Ulyana)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 20"
VERSION_ID="20"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=ulyana
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

#### Git

❯ git --version
git version 2.25.1

#### Examples

> 6e05ecd add v3->v4 migration script to update variables
> https://github.com/rafaelrinaldi/pure/pull/271/commits/6e05ecdad0e4f623050e154e16c0af0315767940

#### Questions

I tried various things:

- removing `~/.Xresources` config related to fonts
- editing then removing `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/30-icons.conf`

Without success, most of the [issues](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st/issues/130) I found were related to [`st` terminal](https://github.com/lukesmithxyz/st). However, I'm not using it but `guake`, and the issue also happened with `yakuake`, `gnome-terminal` and `hyper`

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 42):

As suggested in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/1852985/comments/11, I am able to stop gitk from crashing by installing unifont:

```
sudo apt install unifont
```

Like in the comment, the emoji is displayed in gitk as an empty square, but gitk no longer crashes.

Comment: Nice! This is much better solution since removing `fonts-noto-color-emoji` removes emojis in other apps e.g. chrome.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 but broke emojis in Chrome bookmarks (and probably elsewhere).

Answer (score 34):

After digging with `XFT_DEBUG` flag I found something weird. I run the command with the flag and navigate to the problematic commit:

```
❯ XFT_DEBUG=1 gitk --all
XFT_DEBUG=1
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Medium.ttf: 0 (15.9999 pixels)
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Medium.ttf: 0 (15.9999 pixels)
…
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Medium.ttf: 0 (17.5999 pixels)
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Bold.ttf: 0 (17.5999 pixels)
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf: 0 (17.5999 pixels)
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: 2 (17.5999 pixels)
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: 0 (17.5999 pixels)
XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf: 0 (109 pixels)
X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RenderAddGlyphs)
  Serial number of failed request:  6687
  Current serial number in output stream:  6706
```

Then spotted the last line prior to the fail had an excentric pixel size

> XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: 0 (17.5999 pixels)
>
> XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf: 0 (**109 pixels**)

Removing the `Noto-color-emoji` fonts solved the issue

```
apt remove --purge fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

No more crash and a consistent font size is used to render

> XftFontInfoFill: /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: 2 (17.5999 pixels)

#### Version

```
❯ apt show fonts-noto-color-emoji
…
Version: 0~20200408-1
```

Comment: This answer is not perfect. While it helped with gitk it also removed emojis in other apps e.g. chrome.

Comment: You can't easily remove this package in KDE neon, as `neon-desktop` depends on it.

I ended up temporarily removing the font package with `sudo dpkg -P --force-depends fonts-noto-color-emoji`, re-doing commit of script suggested by github actions with emojis removed from comments, force-push the new git history to github, and reinstalling the fonts-noto-color-emoji package to fix packaging system. What a trap, just because of some emojis in YML config file... *facepalm*. Thank you for your answer, it was essential to make me figure out solution.

Answer (score 13):

From my research, this appears to be a bug in xorg library "libXft" (see issue [libxft#6](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxft/-/issues/6) and pending merge request [libxft!1](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxft/-/merge_requests/1)).

Related discussions:

- Bug report on noto-emoji ([noto-emoji#183](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/issues/183)). Conclusion: It's not a noto-emoji bug.
- A launchpad.net [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/1852985?comments=all) against Ubuntu's git package.
- [This thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg379512.html) on a git mailing list.

As per Édouard's answer, a workaround is to uninstall the `fonts-noto-color-emoji` package (`apt remove --purge fonts-noto-color-emoji`).

Comment: Removing `fonts-noto-color-emoji` may remove emojis in other apps e.g. chrome. Try `unifont` answer which does not have that issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora, I was able to fix a similar error I was getting with `git-gui`, by removing the `google-noto-emoji-color-fonts` package.